# HTML 5 Audio Player remaining time show delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have a problem with an audio player, when users press play the `start-time` timer is showing instantly, but `remaining-time` timer shows with a delay. I'm relatively new to JS, so I can not identify the problem on my own.

Can someone can help me with synching timers (start and remaining) show on play event?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/O1oKCa)

```js
var isSeeking = false;
var seek = document.getElementById("seekObj");
var player = document.getElementById("player");
SetSeekColor();
function calculateTotalValue(length) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(length / 60),
    seconds_int = length - minutes * 60,
    seconds_str = seconds_int.toString(),
    seconds = seconds_str.split(".")[0],
    temp_min = minutes.toString().length === 1 ? "0" + minutes : minutes,
    temp_sec = seconds.toString().length === 1 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  return temp_min + ":" + temp_sec;
}

function calculateCurrentValue(_seconds) {
  function padTime(t) {
    return t < 10 ? "0" + t : t;
  }

  if (typeof _seconds !== "number") return "";
  if (_seconds < 0) {
    _seconds = Math.abs(_seconds);
    //console.log(_seconds);
  }
  var hours = Math.floor(_seconds / 3600),
    minutes = Math.floor((_seconds % 3600) / 60),
    seconds = Math.floor(_seconds % 60);
  var hour = hours > 0 ? padTime(hours) + ":" : "";
  return hour + padTime(minutes) + ":" + padTime(seconds);
}
function setupSeek() {
  seek.max = player.duration;
}
function seekAudio() {
  isSeeking = true;
  player.currentTime = seek.value;
  isSeeking = false;
}
var prevcurrentime = 0;
function initProgressBar() {
  if (!isSeeking) {
    seek.value = player.currentTime;
  }
  var length = player.duration;
  var current_time = player.currentTime;

  // calculate total length of value
  var totalLength = calculateTotalValue(length);


  // calculate current value time
  var currentTime = calculateCurrentValue(current_time);
  if (player.readyState === 4) {
      jQuery(".end-time").html(totalLength);
    jQuery(".start-time").html(currentTime);
  }
  //checking if the current time is bigger than the previous or else there will be sync different between remaining and current
  if (currentTime > prevcurrentime) {
    //calculate the remaining time
    var rem_time = length - current_time;
    jQuery(".rem-time").html(calculateCurrentValue(rem_time));
  }
  //setting the previouscurrent time to this current time
  prevcurrentime = currentTime;

  if (player.currentTime == player.duration) {
    $("#play-btn").removeClass("pause");
  }
}

function initPlayers(num) {
  // pass num in if there are multiple audio players e.g 'player' + i

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    (function() {
      // Variables
      // ----------------------------------------------------------
      // audio embed object
      var playerContainer = document.getElementById("player-container"),
        player = document.getElementById("player"),
        isPlaying = false,
        playBtn = document.getElementById("play-btn");

      // Controls Listeners
      // ----------------------------------------------------------
      if (playBtn != null) {
        playBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          togglePlay();
        });
      }

      // Controls & Sounds Methods
      // ----------------------------------------------------------
      function togglePlay() {
        if (player.paused === false) {
          player.pause();
          isPlaying = false;
          $("#play-btn").removeClass("pause");
        } else {
          $(".start-time").html("");
          player.play();
          $("#play-btn").addClass("pause");
          isPlaying = true;
        }
      }
    })();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please fix all irrelevant errors in your code snippet (e.g. "Uncaught ReferenceError: SetSeekColor is not defined"). The Codepen does not work for me either, as it endlessly keeps reloading the page…

Comment: I checked the CodePen, no errors anywhere (Safari)

Comment: Not sure what your issue really is so I don't know if it will really help, but your are doing `if (currentTime > prevcurrentime) {...` which means currentTime will get updated before rem-time (because currentTime will start at 0 too, and you won't enter that branch). So you might want to handle this case. (many possible ways, like init prevcurrentime to null, or check if it is 0, or even probably other ways)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking good, this is an error in the html. In this piece of code just replace the class `rem-time` by `end-time`.

```
<small style="float: right; position: relative; right: 21px;" class="end-time" onclick="showhideRemaining(this)"></small>
```

Comment: This is not what I'm up to, I need a rem-time **not** end-time

Comment: Yes, i understand but you are setting the end-time in your code first, `jQuery(".end-time").html(totalLength);`, it's not visible at the begining. If you need the `rem-time` set this with te correct value with "totalLength" in the html before manipulate the remaining time.

Comment: For better management of the media player, I advise to use Media events. [mdn media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

Comment: When the player is in playback mode or when the cursor is moved ?

Comment: Ok, i do not see this problem...I just see the launch when you are at 00.04 for example, we have 05:15 for the time remaining but it's normal. If not the concern that we have when seeking with the slider, the time is not updated correctly in the time remaining.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your problem lies within the performance of your code. I can't see a big time difference between the two counters, but here are some suggested improvements:

1. You have the padTime function, so use it (see point 2)!

   ```
   function padTime(t) {
       return t < 10 ? "0" + t : t;
   }
   ```
2. no unnecessary or early conversion to strings:

   ```
   function calculateTotalValue(length) {
       var minutes = Math.floor(length / 60);
       var seconds = Math.floor(length - minutes * 60);

       // use the padTime function here with numbers
       return padTime(minutes) + ":" + padTime(seconds); 
   }
   ```
3. do not query the elements over and over again:

   ```
   if (player.readyState === 4) {
       jQuery(".end-time").html(totalLength);
       jQuery(".start-time").html(currentTime);
   }
   ```

   Here, instead of querying the elements (`jQuery(".end-time")`) every time in your `ontimeupdate` callback, save the references in variables outside of the callback function.
4. limit color updates.

   ```
   setInterval(function() {
       SetSeekColor();
   }, 34);
   ```

   Updating the color every millisecond is just overkill. 34 milliseconds should equal something around 30fps.

---

I noticed you have are planning to have multiple players on one page (`initPlayers(num)`). Here a few thoughts:

- When you initialise the players, save each single player with its UI elements in an Object
- `initPlayers(jQuery("#player-container").length);`: IDs are (must be) unique in an entire HTML Document. This wont work, change it to a class.